# Emailjs - Mime Builder

Tags: mime-message, mime-mail

I'm facing an issue with emailjs-mime-builder

Code

```
var MimeBuilder = require('emailjs-mime-builder')
var rootNode = new MimeBuilder("multipart/mixed"),
childNodeTxt = rootNode.createChild("text/plain").setContent("Text");
childNodeHtml = rootNode.createChild("text/html").setContent("<h1>HTML</h1>");
rootNode.build()
```

Error

MimeBuilder is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

The `emailjs-mime-builder` package is an ES6 Module. Meaning that if you can't use `import` like for example within a `node.js` enviornment, you have to `require` it like this instead:

```
const { default: MimeBuilder } = require( 'emailjs-mime-builder' );
```